# Not able to access id attribute of text tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, attributes

I am not able to access the `id` attribute of the text tag and the lines of savepath function are not working in my javascript code.

```
   function changeIt() {
        var i = 1;
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<br><input  type='text'  id='path' value='For eg: \"C:\\face.txt\"' name='mytext'+ i></input>" + "<br><button id='submitpath' onclick='savepath()'>OK</button>"
    }
    var ipath;
    function savepath()
    {
        ipath = document.getElementById("path").value;
        document.getElementById("path").value = " ";
    }
```

`<body>
    <div id="content-header">
        <h2>EASY EDIT</h2>
        <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
            <br />
            <script>
                var i = 0;
                function myfunction()
                {
                    ++i;
                    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "First select the text you want to use and then Click on the 'Save Selection' button ";
                        image.src = "bo.gif";
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = " ";
                        image.src = "bof.gif";
                    }
                }
            </script>
            <button id="b1" onclick="myfunction()">?Help?</button>
            <img id="myImage" src="bof.gif" width="25" height="50" align="right">
            <p id="para" ></p>
            <button id="get-data-from-selection" class="u">Track Selection</button>
            <button id="writeToFile" >Write the Selections to File</button>
            <div id="my_div"></div>
            <br />
            <div class="results" id="results"></div>
            <p id="a"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>`

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: ya i am  just posting

Comment: the <input> is missing its closing tag

Comment: Tried it still not working

Comment: Input is a self closing tag mate. So you dont need a `</input>`. You just need a `/>` at the end of the input tag. But other than that the `savepath` function is fetching the value correctly. Try `console.log` and see if it is coming as expected.

Comment: But when I try to print the value of Ipath it doesnot print anything.

Comment: In your code, I can't see any assignment for `my_div` like `var my_div = document.getElementById(...)`. Is there anything from your code that you missed to post?

Comment: <div id="my_div"></div>

Comment: its working just fine : http://jsfiddle.net/yw29W/2/

Comment: @user3910959: That is the element being created in HTML, but `my_div` in JS is just an unassigned variable which points to nothing. You have to assign the element to it for the value fetch to work.

Comment: @thecbuilder i dont know what's wrong. It is not working in visual studio 2013. I am making an office app.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a value out of a function, you need to have the function return the value:

```
function savepath()
{
    ipath = document.getElementById("path").value;
    document.getElementById("path").value = " ";
    return ipath;
}
```

Comment: `ipath` is global. I dont think it needs to be returned?